# Choose numbers that add up to a specific number (with a twist)

Tags: prolog

I wanted to solve a riddle in the adventure game 'Book of Unwritten Tales 2' with the help of Prolog to further my knowledge of this specific language.

Find 3 out of 9 numbers that will add to 41.

You have to choose a number three times. Each time the choice is from a fixed different grouping of 3 out of the 9 numbers. The order of the Groups is fixed. The choices are combined with either a minus or plus operand **which is not the sign of the number itself** but tells how it will be algebraically linked with the next number (the twist).

Example Groups to pick from:

1. (65 +)
   (17 -) 
   (37 +)
2. (50 -)
   (23 -)
   (27 +)
3. (33)
   (47)
   (45)

The correct solution would be

```
(65+) (23-) (47) = 41
i.e. 65 + 23 - 47 = 41
```

My program below only finds the following incorrect solution

(17 -) (23 +) (47) = 41

(17 -) (23 -) (47) = -53

which is incorrect since in grouping #2 only (23 -) is available, not (23 +) .

```
addX(X,Y,S) :- X is S - Y.

e(X,S,R) :- ( (addX( X,65,      S),R='65 +') ; (addX( X,17, -1 * S),R = '17 -') ; (addX( X,37,S),R = '37 +') ),X=0.
d(X,S,R) :-   (addX( X,50, -1 * S),R='50 -') ; (addX( X,23, -1 * S),R = '23 -') ; (addX( X,27,S),R = '27 +').
c(X,S,R) :-   (addX( X,33,      S),R='33  ') ; (addX( X,47,      S),R = '47  ') ; (addX( X,45,S),R = '45  ').

solve(Sum,Res5,Res4,Res3) :- c(Xc,Sum,Res3),d(Xd,Xc,Res4),e(Xe,Xd,Res5).

?- solve(41,X1,X2,X3).
X1 = '17 -',
X2 = '23 -',
X3 = 47 ;
false.
```

The problem is that the operators are not applied correctly.
So i tried fixing it by having the sign returned by the nested call.

```
addX(X,Y,S) :- X is S - Y.

e(X,S,R,SI,SO) :- ( (addX( X,65,S),R=65,SO= 1) ; (addX( X,17,S),R = 17,SO= -1) ; (addX( X,37,S),R = 37,SO= 1) ),X=0.
d(X,S,R,SI,SO) :-   (addX( X,SI*50,S),R=50,SO= -1) ; (addX( X,SI*23,S),R = 23,SO= -1) ; (addX( X,SI*27,S),R = 27,SO= 1).
c(X,S,R,SI,SO) :-   (addX( X,SI*33,S),R=33,SO= 1) ; (addX( X,SI*47,S),R = 47,SO= 1) ; (addX( X,SI*45,S),R = 45,SO= 1).

solve(Sum,Res3,Res4,Res5) :- e(Xe,Xd,Res5,1,SO5),d(Xd,Xc,Res4,SO5,SO4),c(Xc,Sum,Res3,SO4,SO3).
```

Unfortunately this results in the following Runtime Error:

```
?- solve(41,X1,X2,X3).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you choose a number from the 3rd group it can't be negative (there are no signs in the 3rd group)?

Comment: There are no operators attached to the third group because the operator is not the sign of the number but tells how the following number will be algebraically linked with it and there is no fourth group in the example. Unfortunately the number of groups is hardcoded in my code, which I hope I will be able to fix.

Comment: If you can choose whether it's `+` or `-`, is the fact that the first group has two pluses and one minus, versus the second having one and two, respectively, important?

Comment: No, you can't choose the operator yourself. If I could they would be all '+' and the problem would be solved as my program works with all positive operators.

Comment: They can't all be plus if it has to total to a specific value like 41. And you have an example with 23+ and another with 23-. I was trying to make sense of the rules.

Comment: (17 -) (23 +) (47) = 41 would be correct

if there was a (23+)  but there only is a (23-)

(17 -) (23 -) (47) = -53

so the solution the Program found is false.

The problem is that I do not know how to apply the operator to the next grouping/number.

Comment: I see, sorry I misunderstood that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a 'declarative' solution  (or is an ugly hack ?) to this nice puzzle

```
:- op(100, xf, +).
:- op(100, xf, -).

test(X,Y,Z) :-
    member(X, [65 +, 17 -, 37 +]),
    member(Y, [50 -, 23 -, 27 +]),
    member(Z, [33  , 47  , 45  ]),
    combine(X, Y, Z, E), 41 is E.

combine(X -, Y -, Z, X - Y - Z).
combine(X -, Y +, Z, X - Y + Z).
combine(X +, Y -, Z, X + Y - Z).
combine(X +, Y +, Z, X + Y + Z).
```

a more generic solution is surprisingly difficult, albeit shorter...

```
test(X,Y,Z) :-
    member(X, [65 +, 17 -, 37 +]),
    member(Y, [50 -, 23 -, 27 +]),
    member(Z, [33  , 47  , 45  ]),
    eval([X, Y, Z], E), 41 is E.
    %combine(X, Y, Z, E), 41 is E.

eval([H|T], E) :- H =.. [Op,N], eval(Op,N,T,E).
eval(Op,X,[H|T], E) :- 
   H =.. [Op1,M], Q =.. [Op,X,M], eval(Op1,Q,T,E)
 ; E =.. [Op,X,H].
```

Comment: I don't think it's an ugly hack. :) It's quite tidy and clear for a 3 term solution (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Since @CapelliC's solution didn't turn out to be an ugly hack, and his and @lurker's are both sufficiently elegant and useful, I thought I'd take the liberty of answering with a truly ugly hack.

This is surely not a good way of solving the problem. But it does work!

```
puzzle(P) :-
    P = [
            ['65 +', '17 -', '37 +'],
            ['50 -', '23 -', '27 +'],
            ['33', '47', '45']
        ].

puzzle_solution(Puzzle, Sum, Expr) :-
    maplist(member, Ps, Puzzle),
    atomic_list_concat(Ps, ' ', ExprAtom),
    term_to_atom(Expr, ExprAtom),
    Sum is Expr.
```

Comment: I really like it (+1). If you don't mind, I stole your `maplist` idea for a moderate variation of the solution I presented.

Comment: @lurker Thanks :) I think I read it is inefficient to do a lot of dynamic construction of atoms and an terms..., but there is a certain naive simplicity to this solution. The only challenge to the puzzle is getting the operator precedence to work out, right? That's where OP got hung up too. I figured, Prolog knows how to sort out precedence if you give it the full expression, so just let it do the work :)  Wouldn't I be a funny kind of jerk if I though I had some particular proprietorial claim over `maplist`? Thanks for giving me a nod for that line though!

Comment: Before your post, I assumed it would be more complicated to use atoms like `'65 +'` to represent the data, but your answer reminded me how clever I wish I was. ;) It may be inefficient, but it's tidy and illustrates a completely different technique for the problem. Since the problem only deals with `+` and `-`, I implicitly assumed a left-to-right evaluation order (natural precedence of `+` and `-` in this case) without asking the OP what was intended. It would be more complicated if it had `*` and `/`. And `maplist`: I just keep forgetting to be clever with it, too. :)

Comment: While jogging this morning I had the same idea, to avoid the distopic usage of (=..)/2, Nice to see in meanwhile you implemented it (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I would take a different approach. First, I would choose a more manipulable representation of the data. Each pairing of number with operation:

1. `[(65,(+)), (17,(-)), (37, (+))]`
2. `[(50, (-)), (23, (-)), (27, (+))]`
3. `[33, 47, 45]`

Here, the number/operation pairs are, `(N, (op))`. This term will let us pick out the number and the operator very easily. The extra parentheses are required around the operator for syntactical reasons in Prolog. You might also choose a form such as, `[[65,+], [17,-], [37,+]]` or `[t(65,+), t(17,-), t(37,+)]`.

Then, to query the problem, I choose to pass this set of information as a list of the above lists. The query would look like:

```
solve(41, [[(65,(+)),(17,(-)),(37,(+))],[(50,(-)),(23,(-)),(27,(+))],[(33),(47),(45)]], Result).
```

I could choose to pass the above 3 lists as separate arguments, but the list of lists is more scalable if you wanted to change the number of lists. What I expect to see for `Result` is the list, in order, of one item chosen from each of the above 3 lists such that the evaluation of that list is 41.

Then a solution would go through each element of the list of lists, select a member from each element, evaluate the results of that selection, and compare that result with the sum argument (in this case, `41`).

```
%  Solve the summation problem

solve(Sum, [C|Choices], [A|Results]) :-
    member(A, C),
    solve(Sum, A, Choices, Results).
solve(Sum, (N1,Op1), [C|Choices], [(N2,Op2)|Results]) :-
    member((N2,Op2), C),
    Term =.. [Op1, N1, N2],
    S is Term,
    solve(Sum, (S,Op2), Choices, Results).
solve(Sum, (N1,Op1), [C], [N2]) :-
    member(N2, C),
    Term =.. [Op1, N1, N2],
    Sum is Term.
```

Running this query:

```
| ?-  solve(41, [[(65,(+)),(17,(-)),(37,(+))],[(50,(-)),(23,(-)),(27,(+))],[(33),(47),(45)]], R).

R = [(65,(+)),(23,(-)),47] ? ;

no
```

By using a variable for the first argument, you can see the possible combinations of results:

```
| ?-  solve(S, [[(65,(+)),(17,(-)),(37,(+))],[(50,(-)),(23,(-)),(27,(+))],[(33),(47),(45)]], R).

R = [(65,(+)),(50,(-)),33]
S = 82 ? ;

R = [(65,(+)),(50,(-)),47]
S = 68 ? ;

R = [(65,(+)),(50,(-)),45]
S = 70 ? ;
...
```

This solution is easily scalable just by varying the lists in 1, 2, and 3 above. You can have two or more lists, or different length lists.

---

And if I may steal aBathologists `maplist` idea, a variation on this solution would be:

```
solve(Sum, Choices, Results) :-
    maplist(member, Results, Choices),
    evaluate(Results, Sum).

evaluate([(N1,Op1), (N2,Op2)|Ops], Sum) :-
    Term =.. [Op1, N1, N2],              % form a term with first two
    S is Term,                           % Evaluate the Term
    evaluate([(S,Op2)|Ops], Sum).        % Evaluate the remaining terms
evaluate([(N1,Op),N2], Sum) :-           % Evaluate last term
    Term =.. [Op, N1, N2],               % Form a term
    Sum is Term.                         % Check final sum
```